# Nginx reverse proxy doesn't work

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, https

After configured TheHive incident response platform,I am trying to configure redirection domain to ip adress but not working.when I write ip adress on browser,I can access web page.It is not possible with domain.I checked with "nslookup thehive.example.com" ,it shows me ip adress correctly.

Note:I redirected domain name to ip adress in our DNS server

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name thehive.example.com;

#  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/thehive_cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/thehive_key.pem;

  proxy_connect_timeout   600;
  proxy_send_timeout      600;
  proxy_read_timeout      600;
  send_timeout            600;
  client_max_body_size    2G;
  proxy_buffering off;
  client_header_buffer_size 8k;

  location / {
    add_header              Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "" ;
  }
}
```

Here curl result

```
curl -v http://thehive.example.com

* Could not resolve host: thehive.example.com
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: thehive.example.com
```

It works when I do curl with ip address

```
 curl -v http://192.168.42.11:9000/index.html
*   Trying 192.168.42.11:9000...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 192.168.42.11 (192.168.42.11) port 9000 (#0)
> GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.42.11:9000
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Request-Time: 1
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
< Last-Modified: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Date: Tue, 21 Dec 2021 05:34:12 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 1191
<
<!doctype html> <html ng-app="thehive"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title ng-bind="'TheHive' + (title ? ' - ' + title : '')"></title> <meta name="description" content=""> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png" /> --> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicons/favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196"> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicons/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96"> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32"> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16"> <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicons/favicon-128.png" sizes="128x128"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor.7dd02a27.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.0688c7a8.css"> <style> app-container { display: block } </style> </head> <body ng-cloak class="hold-transition skin-blue layout-top-nav"> <page-loader flag="isLoading" bg-col* Connection #0 to host 192.168.42.11 left intact
or="#ecf0f5"></page-loader> <div ui-view></div> <script src="scripts/vendor.78eed977.js"></script> <script src="scripts/scripts.dcfd7451.js"></script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: If it works by IP but not DNS name, the problem is almost certainly with DNS. DNS can take a while to propagate - when did you make the changes?

Comment: @shearn89 1 week passed.when I write nslookup blabla.example.com ,it works

Comment: Nice that `nslookup blabla.example.com` works, but the server_name is set to `thehive.example.com`

Comment: @Bob sorry. I mean nslookup thehive.example.com is working correctly

Comment: you have 2 options either show us the logs and tell us what is not working, or tell us the correct name and let us see what is wrong

Comment: @djdomi which logs should I show you? I can do it.This is local system.even you know the domain ,I think it is not  possible to troublehoot it

Comment: please update the question, as it does not reflect the output you gave, please be detailed as possible

Comment: What exactly happens when you access it with domain name? Have you configured the domain name in the app configuration?

Comment: Please use a text based tool to test the request (wget, curl) and share the complete output. Most probably the problem isn't nginx but the backend server.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I edited question.I'm adding the result when I do curl

Answer (score 2):

The `thehive.example.com` does not have a DNS entry. Therefore your browser / `curl` cannot resolve its IP address.

You need to add a DNS entry, or add an entry to the `hosts` file on the system where you are making the request.

Comment: when I write in browser  "thehive.example.com:9000" I can access service without ssl.